# 'module' object has no attribute 'OSMGeoAdmin'

Tags: python, django, gis, gdal, geos

The enviroment is as follows:

```
**Windows 7**
PATH=C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb;C:\Program       Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\OSGeo4W\bin
**python 2.7**
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\bitstring-2.1.1-py2.7.egg',      'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\virtualenvwrapper-2.11.1-py2.7.egg', 'c:\\cygwin\\home\\username\\__prjs\\flt\\requirements\\src\\djangoembed', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info'
```

The few aswers I was able to found sent me to review my GDAL installation and path but it's correct as follows:

```
set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W
set GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin
set GDAL_DATA=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\share\gdal
```

OH! something else is when I am in python and try to call admin.py

```
>>> import django.contrib.gis
>>> import admin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named admin
```

I am working for non-profit project and few are the helpers but much work to be done, so please any idea around this would be very appreaciated.

Based on Rob Wouters' answer I received the root cause error..

```
>>> import django.contrib.gis.admin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\admin\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin import autodiscover, site, AdminSite, ModelAdmin, StackedInline, TabularInline, HORIZONTAL, VERTICAL
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.helpers import ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\helpers.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.util import (flatten_fieldsets, lookup_field,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\util.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    if not settings.DATABASES:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
    self._setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

I will be reading about Django_settings anything I will post what it worked.

The Virtual Enviroment path is as follows:

```
(ve) C:\cygwin\home\holanda\__prjs\ourfield>env
!::=::\
!C:=C:\cygwin\home\holanda\__prjs\ourfield
.
.
.
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=ourfield.settings
.
.
.
GDAL_DATA=C:\OSGeo4W\share\gdal
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH=C:\OSGeo4W\bin
GEOTIFF_CSV=C:\OSGeo4W\share\epsg_csv
.
.
.
HOME=/cygdrive/c/Users/holanda
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\holanda
JAVA_HOME=C:\OSGeo4W\
.
.
.
OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W
PATH=/home/holanda/__prjs/ourfield/ve/Scripts:/cygdrive/c/Python27:/cygdrive/c/Python27/Scripts:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Acronis/SnapAPI:/cygdrive/c/_tech/_mysql/bin:/cygdrive/c/masters/Console2/bin/release:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/bin/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/100/Tools/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/100/DTS/Binn:/cygdrive/c/_tech/utils:/cygdrive/c/MinGW/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime/QTSystem:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Live/Shared:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime/QTSystem:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/cygdrive/c/Python27/Lib/site-packages/MySQLdb:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/bin:/cygdrive/c/OSGeo4W/bin:/cygdrive/c/Users/holanda/AppData/Roaming/Python/Scripts:/cygdrive/c/OSGeo4W/bin:/cygdrive/c/OSGeo4W/apps/msys/bin
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.py;.pyw
.
.
.
PROJECTS_ROOT=C:\cygwin\home\holanda\__prjs
PROJECT_NAME=ourfield
PROJECT_ROOT=C:\cygwin\home\holanda\__prjs\ourfield
PROJ_LIB=C:\OSGeo4W\share\proj
PROMPT=(ve) $P$G
PSModulePath=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
PYTHONPATH=C:\cygwin\home\holanda\__prjs;C:\cygwin\home\holanda\__prjs\ourfield;C:\cygwin\home\holanda\__prjs\ourfield\parts;C:\cygwin\home\holanda\__prjs\ourfield\apps;C:\cygwin\home\holanda\__prjs\ourfield\ve\Lib;C:\cygwin\home\holanda\__prjs\ourfield\ve\Lib\site-packages;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages;C:\OSGeo4W\bin
PYTHONSTARTUP=~/.pythonrc
PYTHON_ROOT=C:\Python27
QTJAVA=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip
QT_PLUGIN_PATH=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Qt4\plugins
QT_RASTER_CLIP_LIMIT=4096
.
.
.
VBOX_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
VIRTUAL_ENV=C:\cygwin\home\holanda\__prjs\ourfield\ve
VS90COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\
WINDIR=C:\Windows
.
.
.
TERM=cygwin
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to `import django.contrib.gis.admin`, not just `admin`.

Comment: True, I was only calling admin, this helped. 
I still received the error regarding enviroment paths..

see below

Comment: I reinstall everything, Ok!, and this is the 3rd time I do it. So wondering which step or file or dll I must be missing.
This is a weird error, no documented so any help any hint, would be great!

Answer (score 3):

I am 4 years late but I got this error after upgrading to osx El capitan and Homebrew. I found the solution [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/7UQ72WW7pgk) `OSMGeoAdmin` relies on gdal so I had to reinstall it after upgrading by running

`brew install gdal`.

hope this might help someone else in the future

Comment: It did help me today. Thank you, sir :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to run `python manage.py shell` from the project directory, this loads the various django specific variables in your shell and will prevent the `ImportError`.

EDIT:

Running it from a batch file and running it from the shell are not the same thing, which is why you are getting these errors.

The easiest way to solve the problem is to create a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-management-commands/), which will avoid all these problems.

Comment: I have Windows 7 env and I have a bat file where I am running manage.py tru this batch file, but yes I run manage.py. That's not the root cause.

Comment: Yeah! well, that's exactly what I've been running and that doesn't help much!
Take a took:
     `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:9999`

Comment: When you run it from the batch file - you need to set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable in the batch file itself.

Comment: I do have DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in the Virtual ENV path:
     `please see below`